# How to store a secret for a plugin inside public_html

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, authentication

My friend has a Wordpress site, I have a django server. I am trying to talk to his Wordpress site custom endpoints of the REST API, and do priviledged activities like create and unpublish posts. I am making a plugin for him.

My friends wordpress hosting has the following structure:

```
public_html
    - wp-admin
    - wp-content
        - plugins
            - My-Shiny-New-REST-Plugin
                - secret.php
    - wp-includes
```

In order for the Wordpress REST API and my server to talk together, I wish for them to both have copies of a secret key. On the wordpress site it will be stored in `secret.php` above. Now what concerns me, as far as I can see is that php code seems to be public (django python code is private). And I imagine secret.php is not very secret at all.

How does one store a secret token for ones plugin in a secure way?

Comment: Php codes are not public. It is only public if the public has access to your server backend. If only your friend and you have the access to his site's server nobody is going to see what you write in your secret.php as long as it is not just plain text. Add the secret as php variable.

Comment: Have you considered just storing it in the database?